# Set up MySQL replication in Google Cloud Platform via Internal IP addresses

Tags: google-compute-engine, mysql-replication

In one of our projects customer security prohibits instances with external IP connections, the instances are on-premise connected via VPN. 
In this project we set up a second network, allowing external connections.

We want to replicate an existing Master MySQL instance in `network-1` (without external IP address) to a new Slave MySQL instance in `network-2` (Google default).

My thought is to connect via the internal IP addresses, but attempts configuring as with normal external addresses seem to fail.

```
user@instance-1:~$ mysql -h 10.132.0.2 -u replicationuser -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.132.0.2' (111)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue:
Using VPC Network Peering:
“Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) Network Peering allows private RFC 1918 connectivity across two VPC networks regardless of whether or not they belong to the same project or the same organization.” https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering
I created a second VPC network, remember to choose manually subnet creation mode and to choose an IP address range that does not conflict with the one in the first VPC network.

Comment: Indeed this is a good way to interconnect two different VPC networks. Just bear in mind that the VPN tunnel in the initial VPC network will not be reachable by the peered VPC network where the slave instance is located [1].
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#vpns_not_reachable_across_peered_networks